# SQL DDL Number range

Tags: sql, constraints, ddl

I an trying to write some DDL code asking for a number range but can't find anything for what I'm looking for on the internet.
So far I have:

```
create table Section (
    c# numeric(10),
    se# numeric(10),
    emp# numeric(5),
    time numeric(5),
    constraint Section_PK primary key (c#, se#),
    constraint Section_FK_Course foreign key (c#) references Course,
    constraint Section_FK_Employee foreign key (emp#) references Employee
)
```

Where my roadblock is, is I need to have "control number" be any number from 40 to 60, and defaulting to 20, while at the same time, if c# is within 3000 to 4000, then control number has to be less than 40.

I'm just really confused how to do this. Is it an 'if then' sort of statement? I haven't done anything like this before and don't know how or where to start looking.

Comment: What is a "control number" and what is its usage?

Comment: @Amit My apologizes, I forgot to add it in to the original list. I was a little confused as to whether or not I should add it in. I _think_, it's supposed to be a `control number numeric(4),` but this is really all the info I've got.

Comment: Is this statement even correct - "I need to have "control number" be any number from 40 to 60, and defaulting to 20"? If it has to be between 40 and 60 how can it default to 20?

Comment: Yes I've double checked, and they want it to be between 40 to 60, but defaulting to 20. I think that just means if it's Null to have 20 be the placeholder. I don't know what kind of logic that is though.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into [check constraint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Check_constraint):

> A check constraint is a type of integrity constraint in SQL which
> specifies a requirement that must be met by each row in a database
> table. The constraint must be a predicate. It can refer to a single or
> multiple columns of the table. The result of the predicate can be
> either TRUE, FALSE, or UNKNOWN, depending on the presence of NULLs. If
> the predicate evaluates to UNKNOWN, then the constraint is not
> violated and the row can be inserted or updated in the table. This is
> contrary to predicates in WHERE clauses in SELECT or UPDATE
> statements.
>
> For example, in a table containing products, one could add a check
> constraint such that the price of a product and quantity of a product
> is a non-negative value:
>
> `PRICE >= 0`
>
> `QUANTITY >= 0`
>
> If these constraints were not in place, it would be possible to have a negative price (−$30) or quantity (−3 items).
>
> Check constraints are used to ensure the validity of data in a
> database and to provide data integrity. If they are used at the
> database level, applications that use the database will not be able to
> add invalid data or modify valid data so the data becomes invalid,
> even if the application itself accepts invalid data.

Different rdbms products implement check constraint differently (some not at all), so check out your rdbms' manual on the check constraint.

Comment: So the constraint check jogged some memory for me. So if I'm understanding this right, initially I would have `control_number numeric(5) default '20'` and then a constraint like: `constraint constraint Section_control_number check (control_number > 40 AND control_number < 60)`

Comment: What about the if 'c# is within 3000 to 4000' condition? I do not see that within your constraint code. But it's your code, your data, you can test the constraint yourself.

Comment: That was my next bridge to cross. And on top of that, I can't actually "test" the code. All the info you have is what I've been given, other than an ERD. My initial though was something like an if-then function, but I know that's not the solution.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I cannot help you any further in this case.

Comment: That's alright. I've had a chance to talk with others in my section and apparently that our best "known" solution for this at this point. Thanks for all the help anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I am more inclined to recommend a `trigger` based approach rather than a `check constraint`. You can't have a `check constraint` constraining the values between 40 and 60 and then a `default` value of 20. They will conflict each other. With the `trigger`, you can implement all these checks and return error messages which will tell the user why the `insert` has failed.

However, you'll have to do some testing to see if the performance of the trigger is at acceptable level.